# I wonder why the author didn't assume that $f,f_1,f_2,\dots$ are bounded functions. Any reason? ("Introduction to Analysis I" by Mitsuo Sugiura)

Tags: normed-spaces, uniform-convergence

I am reading "Introduction to Analysis I" (in Japanese) by Mitsuo Sugiura.

The author wrote the following definition on p.302 in this book:

> Definition 1
> Let $B(A,\mathbb{R}^m)$ be the set of the bounded functions from $A$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$.
> For each $f\in B(A,\mathbb{R}^m)$, $$||f||=\sup_{x\in A} |f(x)|$$ is called the uniform norm of $f$.
> Let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of functions on $A$.
> When $\lim_{n\to\infty} ||f-f_n||=0$, we say $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $A$.

I wonder why the author didn't assume that $f,f_1,f_2,\dots$ are elements of $B(A,\mathbb{R}^m).$
Any reason?

Comment: They need not be, the definition of uniform convergence does not require the functions to be bounded.

Comment: $f$ will be bounded if the $f_n$s re bounded, so there is no need to assume that on $f$. But otherwise, there is no harm done by extending the definition a bit.

Comment: @GBA Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @BrunoB Thank you very much for your  comment.